# Migrating to PhpSpreadsheet from PhpExcel

Tags: symfony, migration, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I'm about to migrate the PhpExcel (with Liuggio bundle) to PhpSpreadsheet (Yectep bundle). I wanted to do it a step at a time, so not replacing all of them at once, but one Excel report at a time - at least until I'm sure the new thing works as it should.

When trying to load the yectep service, it fails, because the old PhpExcel auto loader gets called/involved instead of new the one.

Does that mean that we definitely can NOT use both of those plugins at the same time?

Comment: This might help with pure `PHPExcel` to `PHPSpreadsheet` migration: https://getrector.org/blog/2020/04/16/how-to-migrate-from-phpexcel-to-phpspreadsheet-with-rector-in-30-minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I did not make it with running the two Symfony bundles together (Liuggio and Yectep), so I presumed that `PhpSpreadsheet` can't run together with `PhpExcel` neither.

A colleague of mine managed to do it with `Roromix/phpspreadsheet` Symfony bundle.
After removing the `yectep` bundle and installing that one, all worked perfectly.

So, to answer my own question - the answer is technically *NO*, since you actually **CAN** use the `PhpExcel` and `PhpSpreadsheet` together - just not with all Symfony plugins.